# SQL Server Project Automate Unit Testing

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing

I have a SQL Server (2012) project in VS2013. I also have an app.config with Local configuration and [tfsbuildserver].sqlunittest.config with server connection string and a relative path.

When performing a check-in executes a build definition that makes deploy and run the tests. The deploy done correctly, but when tests throws me the following error:

> **An error occurred while SQL Server unit testing settings were being read from the configuration file.  Click the test project, open the
>   SQL Server Test Configuration dialog box from the SQL menu, add the
>   settings to the dialog box, and rebuild the project.**

app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SqlUnitTesting" type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.Configuration.SqlUnitTestingSection, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </configSections>
  <SqlUnitTesting AllowConfigurationOverride="true">
    <DatabaseDeployment DatabaseProjectFileName="[RELATIVEPATHLOCAL]"
      Configuration="Release" />
    <DataGeneration ClearDatabase="true" />
    <ExecutionContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=[LOCALSERVER];Initial Catalog=[DATABASE];Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
      CommandTimeout="30" />
    <PrivilegedContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=[LOCALSERVER];Initial Catalog=[DATABASE];Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
      CommandTimeout="30" />
  </SqlUnitTesting>
</configuration>
```

[tfsbuildserver].sqlunittesting.config:

```
<SqlUnitTesting>
  <DatabaseDeployment DatabaseProjectFileName="[RELATIVEPATHTFS]"
    Configuration="Release" />
  <DataGeneration ClearDatabase="true" />
  <ExecutionContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=[SERVERTEST];Initial Catalog=[DATABASETEST];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[USER];Password=[PASS];Pooling=False"
    CommandTimeout="30" />
  <PrivilegedContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=[SERVERTEST];Initial Catalog=[DATABASETEST];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[USER];Password=[PASS];Pooling=False"
    CommandTimeout="30" />
</SqlUnitTesting>
```

Tests run correctly locally. The error occurs when performing the build definition

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I had leading white space before the `<SqlUnitTesting>`, once these were removed the test ran as expected and remove

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

URL: [Link Resolved](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2011/09/12/expected-to-find-an-element-error-when-running-vs2010-database-unit-tests.aspx)